# if, elsif, else statements html erb beginner

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I'm having problems with an if, elsif, else statment in html.erb.  I've seen a lot of questions around the if/else statements in erb but none that include elsif so I thought I'd ask for help.

Here is my html.erb:

```
<% if logged_in? %>

          <ul class = "nav navbar-nav pull-right">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Account <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                  <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                  <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li>
                    <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: "delete" %>
            </li>
          </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>



     <% elsif has_booth?(current_user.id) %>

      <ul>

        <li>TEST</li>

      </ul>



<% else %>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", signup_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
        </ul>
      <% end %>
```

Here is my has_booths method:

```
module BoothsHelper

def has_booth?(user_id)
  Booth.exists?(user_id: user_id)
end 

end
```

I would like the header nav to have three different types of content for different users.  The logged in user, the logged in user that has created a booth, and the logged out user.  So far, I can only seem to make 2 out of the three work.  I tried changing

```
<% elsif has_booth?(current_user.id) %>
```

to

```
<% elsif logged_in? && has_booth?(current_user.id) %>
```

and that did not work either.  Am I writing my statement correctly?  Any thoughts appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is that your first condition is true, so it stops there. Your first condition:

```
<% if logged_in? %>
```

Even if they don't have a booth it will never reach the elsif because the first condition is true. You either need:

```
<% if logged_in? && has_booth?(current_user.id) %>
  // code
<% elsif logged_in? && !has_booth?(current_user.id) %>
  // code
<% else %>
  // code
<% end %>
```

Or it might be a cleaner approach to separate them into two if/else:

```
<% if logged_in? %>
  <% if has_booth?(current_user.id) %>
    // code
  <% else %>
    // code
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  // code
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I implemented the first solution and it worked.  As for the cleaner, would the first code block be if both instances were true, the second if only logged_in? were true and the third block for the else?  Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, and yup that's right with the way you outlined the cleaner approach.

Answer (score 1):

An even cleaner approach would be to flatten the statement, handling the not logged-in condition first so you don't have to test it along with whether they have a booth:

```
<% if !logged_in? %>
  // not logged in code
<% elsif has_booth?(current_user.id) %>
  // logged in and has booth code
<% else %> 
  // logged in and does not have booth code
<% end %>
```

You could also have used `unless logged_in?`, but the else and elsif don't make as much sense, semantically, with unless and therefore it doesn't read as clearly.